# Как дать имена выводимым идентификаторам?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой кусочек кода:

```
"+zak['test']+"
```

test выводит идентификатор, например 1, а в ряде случаев 2 или 3. Вопрос в следующем, как дать имена этим цифрам?
Что-то вроде 1 = холодно 2 = тепло 3 = жарко

Чтоб в за место цифр выводились эти имена.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вариантов много. Начинают с

```
let x = "";
if(zak.test == 1) x = "холодно"
else ...
console.log("something" + x + "else");
```

затем вариант

```
switch(zak.test) {
    case 1: ...
}
```

потом, т.к. значения цифровые

```
let values = [, 'холодно', ....];
console.log(values[zak.test]);
```

и общий случай для произвольных (нецелочисленных) ключей

```
const values = { 1: "холодно", ....}
console.log( values[zak.test])
```